# Expected expression error with %

Tags: c

I'm trying just to get my code to compile to see if it all works like planned, but I keep getting the error

> c:44: error: expected expression before â%â token

My code is below

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc<1)
    {
      printf("Incorrect number of arguements\n");
      return 0;
    }

    Player* head = NULL;
    Player* node = NULL;
    char name[NAME_LENGTH], champion[CHAMP_LENGTH], team[TEAM_LENGTH];
    char temp;
    int kills, deaths = 0;
    FILE *in = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    while (1)
    {               /*error is here*/
      fscanf(in, "%s%c%s%c%s%c%d%c%d%c", name, &temp, champion, %temp, team, &temp, &kills, &temp, &deaths, &temp); 
      if (feof(in)) break;

      node = new_player(name, champion, team, kills, deaths);
      head = insert_by_player(head, node);

    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: With such a long `fscanf()`, checking its return value is a good programming practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `%temp` instead of `&temp` in the parameter list of `fscanf`.

But note that you can write:

```
fscanf("%d%*c%d", &a, &b);
```

The `"%*c"` means read but then ignore a character, so you do not need the dummy `&temp` at all.

Comment: Ahh I thought it had something to do with the input code itself. Thanks for the help!